# Pandas pivot dataframe and setting the new columns as True/False based on if they existed or not

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

As the title states I want to pivot my dataframe (I believe it needs to be pivoted?)

Let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                   'REV' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   'GROUP' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]})


+----+-----+-------+
| ID | REV | GROUP |
+----+-----+-------+
|  0 |   0 |     1 |
|  0 |   0 |     2 |
|  1 |   1 |     1 |
|  1 |   1 |     2 |
|  1 |   1 |     3 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

I want to do some kind of pivot so my result of the table looks like

```
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
| ID | REV |  1   |  2   |   3   |
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
|  0 |   0 | True | True | False |
|  1 |   1 | True | True | True  |
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
```

Now the values from the GROUP column becomes there own column. The value of each of those columns is T/F based on if the original df had that group or not.

Any recommendations? This seems like a pivot thing, but I am a big noob when it comes to working with pivots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab([df.ID,df.REV],df.GROUP).ne(0).reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1)
out
   ID  REV     1     2      3
0   0    0  True  True  False
1   1    1  True  True   True
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `get_dummies` and then `groupby` with `any`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(["ID", "REV"]).GROUP).groupby(level=[0,1]).any()


           1     2      3
ID REV                   
0  0    True  True  False
1  1    True  True   True
```

You can add `reset_index` if you want the `ID` and `REV` columns as columns instead of the index:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(["ID", "REV"]).GROUP).groupby(level=[0,1]).any().reset_index()

   ID  REV     1     2      3
0   0    0  True  True  False
1   1    1  True  True   True
```

Comment: Hmm, why are the new column 'above' the old one's? and how would that affect a join I would want to do later on by ID and REV? Ultimately I want to join this result with another df by ID and REV, and I'd like the 1, 2, etc... columns to be on the same level as all others

Comment: See my edit, those columns were in the index, but you can just add `reset_index()` to get them back

Comment: Thank you for the help! Quick question, what does groupby(level=[0,1]) do?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dummy column which is the same with `GROUP`, then use that dummy column as value in `pivot_table()`.

```py
df['GROUP_'] = df['GROUP']

df_ = ~ pd.pivot_table(df, index=['ID', 'REV'], columns='GROUP', values='GROUP_').isna()
```

```
print(df_)

GROUP      1     2      3
ID REV                   
0  0    True  True  False
1  1    True  True   True

print(df_.reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1))

   ID  REV     1     2      3
0   0    0  True  True  False
1   1    1  True  True   True
```

Comment: Thanks, also how you made your GROUP col on top of the ID REV cols seems super useful for other stuff. Thanks!