# Pandas crosstab dataframe and setting the new columns as True/False/Null based on if they existed or not and based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, crosstab

As the title states I want to pivot/crosstab my dataframe

Let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                   'REV' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   'GROUP' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                   'APPR' : [True, True, NULL, NULL, True})


+----+-----+-------+------+
| ID | REV | GROUP | APPR |
+----+-----+-------+------+
|  0 |   0 |     1 | True |
|  0 |   0 |     2 | True |
|  1 |   1 |     1 | NULL |
|  1 |   1 |     2 | NULL |
|  1 |   1 |     3 | True |
+----+-----+-------+------+
```

I want to do some kind of pivot so my result of the table looks like

```
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
| ID | REV |  1   |  2   |   3   |
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
|  0 |   0 | True | True | False |
|  1 |   1 | NULL | NULL | True  |
+----+-----+------+------+-------+
```

Now the values from the GROUP column becomes there own column. The value of each of those columns is T/F/NULL based on APPR only for the T/NULL part. I want it be False when the group didn't exist for the ID REV combo.

similar question I've asked before, but I wasn't sure how to make this answer work with my new scenario:
[Pandas pivot dataframe and setting the new columns as True/False based on if they existed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319391/pandas-pivot-dataframe-and-setting-the-new-columns-as-true-false-based-on-if-the)

Hope that makes, sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to pivot?

```
pd.pivot(df, index=['ID','REV'], columns=['GROUP'], values='APPR').fillna(False).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hmm, so I just tried this. The issue becomes that both the NULLs and False become the same result

Comment: Okay was able to change your answer a bit and get the result I wanted. Thank you!